# How to write the data from two variable into a File python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a log file where i'm fetching only the desired output and into two different variables and when i run the code it prints currently but i need both the variable data written into another file called `file1`.
I have the raw code sample which i tried working with print but not getting the idea about writing it into a file.

```
with open("testfile","r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if "ping" in line:
            if HOST != "NA" and Flag:
                mydata1 = hostname  

        elif HOST != "NA" and Flag and HOST not in mydata1:
            mydata2 = logname
            mydata3 = open('file1', 'w')
            mydata3.write(mydata1,mydata2)
    mydata3.close()
#print(mydata1,mydata2)
```

Comment: This line might be causing some problem `lif HOST != "NA" and Flag and HOST not in mydata1:`

Comment: Your code is really confusing. What is `hostname` or `logname`? Please make a reproducible example. Also, there is the `logging` module designed for logging; is there a reason you're not using that?

Comment: @Rakesh, it works perfectly while printing , however i'm not sure about my new file writing if thats correct or not.

Comment: @roganjosh, as i said raw code becuae it has some company data hence i snipped the real data and Just kept sample for the sake of variable names which shows it has data. However its not system logging , its kind of slef created log data where we don't hve option to use `logging` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str.format`:

**Ex:**

```
with open("testfile","r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if "ping" in line:
            if HOST != "NA" and Flag:
                mydata1 = hostname

        elif HOST != "NA" and Flag == True and HOST not in mydata1:
            mydata2 = logname
            mydata3 = open('file1', 'w')
            mydata3.write("{0} {1}".format(mydata1,mydata2))
    mydata3.close()
```

Comment: let me try the provided.

Comment: it would be easier, or at least for me, to put `mydata1 + " " + mydata2`, or if they use 3.6, `f"{mydata1} {mydata}"`

Comment: @IvánC.. You can use that also. I am just used to `str.format` :)

Comment: @IvánC.. Would you be able to provide the way which you are talking about in my case above, i'm sorry for my golden fish memory syndrom :)

Comment: @Rakesh, i was Just adjusting format tofit my code and now it works with using `str.format`, Great thnx. Would you be able to explain the logic behind.

Comment: @pygo..I am just joining both your variable into a single string and then writing it to the file.

Comment: @Rakesh, Got it , tried IvánC simple concatenation both works Greatly.